# logo/user avatar update in angular

Tags: angular, routes, parameter-passing

I have a header top component to display loged user avatar and company logo, and also in my home page component I have image uploader to change the avatar. Every time I change the image it is uploading, but the image wont changing in the header.

I used component reloading using this code

```
const currentRoute = this.router.url + '?provider=' + this.provider;
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
this.router.navigate([currentRoute]); // navigate to same route
});
```

but it is throwing error no route found, because of the parameter passing in the route.

Is this a right method ?
How do i pass  a data in route navigate, which is not given in routes data in routing module?
in my routing module I am only specified the path, but not parameters

```
{
path: 'home',
component: HomeComponent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {}


this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  // do smth with params['provider'];
 });
```

}

Maybe you should try something like this?